# Beautifulsoup extract div by its class name

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a table from a html page,

Following is the code I have tried,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/krish/Desktop/Python/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.marketsmojo.com/Stocks?StockId=592009&Exchange=0#navQuality')
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.find_element_by_id("table1 comp2-table ng-tns-c94-1"),'lxml')
tables = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "card ng-tns-c94-1"})
hdfc_mm = pd.read_html(str(tables))
```

I am trying to extract a table from quality menu bar, from the website mentioned.After that I given a name by using inspect on the table and found the table name with divsion class also.

But I received following error,

Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="table1 comp2-table ng-tns-c94-1"]"}

[image]

highlighted the required table.

How to find the table? Any ideas please.

Thanks

Comment: Have you signed in into the site?
Apparently on opening the link a pop up come up and ask to make account or sign in. I guess therefore you are unable to find that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from an API on :

```
GET https://frapi.marketsmojo.com/stocks_quality/cardinfo?std={id}
```

It needs the id from the url query parameters :

```py
import requests

sid = "592009"

r = requests.get(f"https://frapi.marketsmojo.com/stocks_quality/cardinfo?sid={sid}")
print(r.json()["data"]["quality_tbl"]["list"])
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/PythonMarketMojo)